# How to render a complex JSON array of array in React

Tags: html, arrays, reactjs

I am new to React JS, I want to render this JSON containing Category and list of items below that category. Consider state.miData has this array response from server. It has category and list of menu items under that category. I want to show it in  UI like Category and under that category list of items those fall in that category.

```
[
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "Pasta",
      "id": "P1"
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "menuItemId": "1",
        "menuItemName": "Alfredo-Pasta"
      },
      {
        "menuItemId": "2",
        "menuItemName": "Macroni-Pasta"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "Burger",
      "id": "B1"
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "menuItemId": "2",
        "menuItemName": "UB-Burger"
      },
      {
        "menuItemId": "1",
        "menuItemName": "Thela-Mela-Burger"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have written this code in render function but its not working.

```
const data = this.state.miData
const listItems = data.map((d) => 
        <div>
            <p key={d.category.id}>{d.category.name}</p> 
            <ul>
              d.items.map((mi) =>
                <li>{mi.menuItemName}</li>
              );
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
return (
    <div>
        {listItems}  
    </div>  
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: add key={mi.menuItemId} to the <li> element to avoid the warning

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping up the map for the list item in the curly braces.

```
<ul>
 {
   d.items.map((mi) =>
    <li>{mi.menuItemName}</li>
   );
 }
</ul>
```